# AvalonEdit - Syntax Highlighting - How do I add underline, change font size, etc?

Tags: avalonedit

I'm trying to build a basic, Markdown-style plain/rich text editor. (One where the text is styled inline, instead of having two panels side-by-side the way most Markdown editors do) (I'm also not going to support the full Markdown spec - no lists or tables, mainly just rich text formatting like bold, italics, underline, etc)

I have a project that consumes the AvalonEdit project (via the source code, not the Nuget package) - I got the editor all setup exactly how I want - then I started to write a syntax highlighting XSHD file when I realized that the highlighter only supports formatting like font colors, italics, bold, etc and not font size, underline and others...

How can I add additional font formatting? Will I have to write a whole new parser/highlighter/whatever? Is there an easy way to hook into and extend the existing highlighter?

I've already made a few small changes to one file in the source (TextEditor.xaml), and I'm willing to change more to make this work - though when I started I was hoping to touch the source as little as possible...

If someone could just point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it - Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the syntax highlighting documentation](http://avalonedit.net/documentation/html/4d4ceb51-154d-43f0-b876-ad9640c5d2d8.htm):

> Among the text rendering extension points is the support for "visual
>   line transformers" that can change the display of a visual line after
>   it has been constructed by the "visual element generators". A useful
>   base class implementing IVisualLineTransformer for the purpose of
>   syntax highlighting is DocumentColorizingTransformer. Take a look at
>   that class' documentation to see how to write fully custom syntax
>   highlighters. This article only discusses the XML-driven built-in
>   highlighting engine.

Having read and/or scanned through that page a number of times, I couldn't fully grok this until I'd looked through the code a bit more, read some posts on [the SharpDevelop forums](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/), etc.

And if you're at the same stage I was (and can't quite wrap your head around that quote), the gist is that the editor does these two things (simplified, of course):

1. It generates lines of visible text (it only bothers with the lines
   currently visible on the screen for performance reasons)
2. It then runs various transformers over said generated text, to style it in various ways

So the "XML-driven built-in highlighting engine" is only one way to find and style text - one that's meant to be a simple implementation of the more 'advanced' way, which is to build a custom text transformer, like a DocumentColorizingTransformer.

And here's some info on DocumentColorizingTransformer that you may find useful (besides the API documentation they point you to):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23251990/859833

http://danielgrunwald.de/coding/AvalonEdit/rendering.php